# Use text-button in the Android actionbar instead of icons

Tags: android

Would be appropriate to use a text-button in the Android actionbar instead of an icon?

In the detail I have a form-view where the user have to select several elements and perform a saving operation when done. So far I'm using an checkmark icon in the top-right of the actionbar.

Now I'm getting a request to change that checkmark icon to a "Done" button. The request come from an ex-ios-user.

In term of Android UX would be appropriate to replace that checkmark icon with a "Done" button? Or it would be just an iOS porting?

Comment: A bunch of Android applications use CTA's instead of icons in the action bar, Facebook and Twitter just to name two. Just make sure that YOU stay consistent within the app, and don't worry about Gmail for example using an arrow-paper plane instead of a CTA in the action bar, it doesn't mean you have to follow the exact same pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a text button in ActionBar is fine if it's only one button. It even makes more sense than an icon. A right sided text "DONE" button in actionBar is very common and makes sense.
But if you have more than one (or two) button in the actionBar, I'd advise to stick with the icons.